# Not able to build the created Titanium Android Module

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-modules

I had created Titanium Android Module using the Commadline commands in my Windows7 machine, when I try to build the created module using **Ant** it shows the following error

```
C:\Users\ram\modtest>ant
Buildfile: C:\Users\ram\modtest\build.xml

init:

process.annotations:

generate.rhino.bindings:
     [java] Generating C:\Users\ram\modtest\build\generated\java\com\ram\apptest
\ExampleProxyPrototype.java
     [java] Generating C:\Users\ram\modtest\build\generated\java\com\ram\apptest
\ModtestModulePrototype.java
     [java] Generating C:\Users\ram\modtest\build\generated\java\modtestGenerate
dBindings.java

generate.rhino.idswitch:
     [echo] Generating IDs for C:\Users\ram\modtest\build\generated\java\com\ram
\apptest\ExampleProxyPrototype.java
     [echo] Generating IDs for C:\Users\ram\modtest\build\generated\java\com\ram
\apptest\ModtestModulePrototype.java
     [echo] Generating IDs for C:\Users\ram\modtest\build\generated\java\modtest
GeneratedBindings.java

generate.v8.bindings:
     [java] Generating C:\Users\ram\modtest\build\generated\jni\com.ram.apptest.
ExampleProxy.h
     [java] Generating C:\Users\ram\modtest\build\generated\jni\com.ram.apptest.
ExampleProxy.cpp
     [java] Generating C:\Users\ram\modtest\build\generated\jni\com.ram.apptest.
ModtestModule.h
     [java] Generating C:\Users\ram\modtest\build\generated\jni\com.ram.apptest.
ModtestModule.cpp

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\ram\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\1.8.0.1\module\android\bui
ld.xml:103: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Users\ra
m\AppData\Roaming\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\1.8.0.1\module\android\bootstrap.py":
 CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:593)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute$Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Exec
ute.java:862)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.launch(Execute.java:481)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.execute(Execute.java:495)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(ExecTask.java:631)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:672)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTask.java:498)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav
a:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExe
cutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32
 application
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:81)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:30)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:453)
        ... 23 more

Total time: 6 seconds
```

Is there is any way to fix it...?

Answer (score 1):

this is a known [bug](http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-6685) and won't be fixed until release 1.8.1 which I'm not sure when it's coming out. you can't build modules for windows platforms with 1.8.0.1. seems par for the course with titanium software.

Answer (score 0):

I see it is not able to execute the python script. if you have python installed on your machine make sure to add it to the PATH environment variable.